# What is the Difference between will resume and will be resumed?

Tags: verbs, modal-verbs

Are these two sentences grammatically correct and does the meaning is same?

Here are the two sentences using *will resume* and *will be resumed*.
What is correct here? Also, is it true that *will* should always be followed by *be*?

> 1) Or it was like I can come to New Zealand on family visitor visa again so that after completing 1 month 2 weeks, my residential visa application process **will  be resumed**.
>
> 2) Or it was like I can come to NZ on family visitor visa again so that after completing 1 month 2 weeks, my residential visa application process **will resume**.

Answer (score 0):

They are both correct, with slightly different connotations.
The first sentence is in the passive voice, suggesting that somebody, i.e. the Immigration Office, the police, the government, will resume the application process.
The second sentence is in the active voice and it suggests that the process (an activity) will continue.
You are good either way.
Edit: No, "will" does not always have to be followed by "be", generally only in the passive voice.

Comment: Will+be is used in passive voice and progressive aspect.